# ngbPopover will not close and will open on load

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I want to show the popover once the page load or without trigerring the button and will never close
I'm using ngbPopover in Angular.

`<button placement="left" (click)="openQuestionnaire()" [ngbPopover]="popContent" >0/4</button>`

using the reference here : https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover/examples

Comment: Elaborate your question.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add this property to your button:

```
[autoClose]="false"
```

Then your button would look like this:

```
<button placement="left" 
        (click)="openQuestionnaire()" 
        [ngbPopover]="popContent" 
        [autoClose]="false" >0/4</button>
```

---

From the link you shared i found this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary mr-2" 
        ngbPopover="What a great tip!" 
        [autoClose]="false" 
        triggers="manual" 
        #p="ngbPopover" 
        (click)="p.open()" 
         popoverTitle="Pop title">
             Click me to open a popover
</button>
```

As per your comment, you can trigger it when your component is shown in the page:

```
<button placement="left" 
        #pop="ngbPopover"
        (click)="openQuestionnaire()" 
        [ngbPopover]="popContent" 
        [autoClose]="false" >0/4</button>
```

in your component class:

```
ngOnInit(){
    if(!pop.isOpen()){
        pop.open();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to show automatically without triggering the button ?

Comment: You can trigger it in the `ngOnInit(){ p.open(); }`. here `p` is the template reference variable `#p`.

Comment: Did you use any constructor to define the popover you used in if(!popover.isOpen()){
        pop.open();
    }

Comment: By the way just letting you know I have the (click)="openQuestionnaire()"  to open the modal  ... If I do use it on ngOnInit() the modal also will be triggered at the same time

Comment: @marjorieasensi i think this would just open the popover because it is not triggering the click event eventually.

Comment: just now getting this error --> No provider for NgbPopover!